# twig file in theme about user log in not working

Tags: wordpress, twig

i need to use this

```
 <?phpif ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
echo 'Welcome, registered user!';} else {
echo 'Welcome, visitor!';}?>
```

in .twig wordpress

in this theme

http://themeforest.net/item/realia-responsive-real-estate-wordpress-theme/4789838

but i try this

```
{% if is_granted("ROLE") %}
    Hi {{ app.user.username }}
{% endif %}
```

get error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Twig_Error_Syntax' with message 'The function "is_granted" does not exist in "single-property.twig"
```

pls if i'm wrong post forgive me this frist time to use this web

very thank you all comment

Comment: `is_granted` is a symfony2 function given to twig, aka not available in wordpress. Without seeing that variables they are passing the template i couldnt really tell you how to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will of any use anymore but I figured it out because I was trying to make the same thing on the Realia Theme, I wanted to show some fields just to logged in users, and I realized that at least on Realia all the twigs have wp. before the call to action, for example I achieved what you needed adding this to the twig files

```
{% if  wp.is_user_logged_in %}

My content here

{% else %}

Other content

{% endif %}
```